# SQL count Not sure How to get it to work with model, view and controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I am not sure on how to do this with the model, view, and controller. I currently have it in the view only. I know this is bad practice that is why I am trying to see if I can get help. I have google how to create count but I cannot find any tutorials on this. Any help would be appreciated also this code is working.

view page

```
 ?php $this->db->where('status','Happy');
    $this->db->from('data');
    $count = $this->db->count_all_results();?>

    <a href='http://google.com'><?php echo 'Happy =' . $count;
    ?></a><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model

```html
<!-- model.php -->
<?php
  
  class Model extends CI_Model{
    
    public fucntion __construct(){
    
      $this->load->database();
    }

    public function count(){
      
      
      $this->db->select(*);
      $this->db->from('data');
      $this->db->where('status','Happy');
      $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
      
      return $count;
      
    }

  }
?>
```

Controller

```html
<!-- controller.php -->

<?php
    
  class Controller extends CI_controller{

    public function __construct(){
      
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
  
      $this->load->model('model');
      $data['result'] = $this->Model->count();
      $this->load->view('printresult',$data);
    
    }

  }




?>
```

View

Comment: I also get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*'